# Android Arduino Bluetooth weird errors connecting microcontroller

Tags: java, android, c, bluetooth, arduino

I am using a Teensy microcontroller (https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/teensy31.html) to connect to an Android application to get Bluetooth.

I have used this Android application with other embedded bluetooth devices successfully, however now I am running into the following error I see in LogCat:

04-02 20:06:29.713: E/BTLD(5499):

```
######################################################################
04-02 20:06:29.713: E/BTLD(5499): #
04-02 20:06:29.713: E/BTLD(5499): # WARNING : BTU HCI(id=0) command timeout. opcode=0x405
04-02 20:06:29.713: E/BTLD(5499): #
04-02 20:06:29.713: E/BTLD(5499): ######################################################################
```

I have zero idea where this error is coming from. I also see the following error occasionally:

```
04-02 20:25:19.242: E/bt-btif(914): DISCOVERY_COMP_EVT slot id:11, failed to find channle,                                       status:1, scn:0
```

**The worst part is, with my current hardware setup, half the time it will work, the other half it wont.** And I have no clue why. For reference, I am using this bluetooth module: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12577 And I have the pins connected:

```
Vcc <---> Vcc
GND <---> GND
TX (BT) <---> RX1 (Teensy)
RX (BT) <---> TX1 (Teensy)
```

The lack of consistency is killing me. Sometimes just pushing the reset button on the Teensy fixes it.

I am working off of this tutorial: http://stafava.blogspot.ca/2012/12/connect-teensy-to-bluetooth-module.html Here is the Ardunio Microcontroller code running on the Teensy:

```
HardwareSerial bt = HardwareSerial();

#define  Seria1_PORT_SPEED  115200

void setup()
{
    bt.begin(Seria1_PORT_SPEED);
    bt.println();
    Wire.begin();


}

void loop()
{  

  ////////////////// Bluetooth stuff /////////////////////////
  if (bt.available() >= 2) {
    if (bt.read() == '#') {// Start of new control message 
      int command = bt.read(); // Commands
      if (command == 'f') {// request one output _f_rame
        //output_single_on = true; //unused?
      } else if (command == 's') { // _s_ynch request
        // Read ID
        byte id[2];
        id[0] = readChar();
        id[1] = readChar();

        // Reply with synch message
        bt.print("#SYNCH");
        bt.write(id, 2);
        bt.println();
      }
    }
  }

  sendDataToAndroid();
}




void sendDataToAndroid() { //arrays defined as float array[3] = ...

  bt.write((byte*) array1, 12);
  bt.write((byte*) array2, 12);
  bt.write((byte*) array3, 12);

}

char readChar()
{
  while (bt.available() < 1) { } // Block
  return bt.read();
}
```

And here is the relevant Android code taken from this tutorial: https://github.com/ptrbrtz/razor-9dof-ahrs/tree/master/Arduino/Razor_AHRS

```
package com.jest.razor;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.apache.http.util.EncodingUtils;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Class to easily interface the Razor AHRS via Bluetooth.
 * <p>
 * Bluetooth seems to be even more picky on Android than it is anyway. Be sure to have a look at the
 * section about Android Bluetooth in the tutorial at
 * <a href="https://github.com/ptrbrtz/razor-9dof-ahrs">
 * https://github.com/ptrbrtz/razor-9dof-ahrs</a>!
 * <p>
 * The app using this class has to
 * <ul>
 * <li>target Android 2.0 (API Level 5) or later.
 * <li>specify the uses-permissions <code>BLUETOOTH</code> and <code>BLUETOOTH_ADMIN</code> in it's
 * AndroidManifest.xml.
 * <li>add this Library Project as a referenced library (Project Properties -> Android -> Library)
 * </ul>
 * <p>
 * TODOs:
 * <ul>
 * <li>Add support for USB OTG (Android device used as USB host), if using FTDI is possible.
 * </ul>
 * 
 * @author Peter Bartz
 */
public class RazorAHRS {
    private static final String TAG = "RazorAHRS";
    private static final boolean DEBUG = false;
    private static final String SYNCH_TOKEN = "#SYNCH";
    private static final String NEW_LINE = "\r\n";

    // Timeout to init Razor AHRS after a Bluetooth connection has been established
    public static final int INIT_TIMEOUT_MS = 10000;

    // IDs passed to internal message handler
    private static final int MSG_ID__YPR_DATA = 0;
    private static final int MSG_ID__IO_EXCEPTION_AND_DISCONNECT = 1;
    private static final int MSG_ID__CONNECT_OK = 2;
    private static final int MSG_ID__CONNECT_FAIL = 3;
    private static final int MSG_ID__CONNECT_ATTEMPT = 4;
    private static final int MSG_ID__AMG_DATA = 5;

    private static final UUID UUID_SPP = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    /**
     * Razor output modes.
     * Use <code>YAW_PITCH_ROLL_ANGLES</code> to receive yaw, pitch and roll in degrees. <br>
     * Use <code>RAW_SENSOR_DATA</code> or <code>CALIBRATED_SENSOR_DATA</code> to read raw or
     * calibrated xyz sensor data of the accelerometer, magnetometer and the gyroscope.
     */
    public enum RazorOutputMode {
        YAW_PITCH_ROLL_ANGLES,
        RAW_SENSOR_DATA,
        CALIBRATED_SENSOR_DATA
    }
    private RazorOutputMode razorOutputMode;

    private enum ConnectionState {
        DISCONNECTED,
        CONNECTING,
        CONNECTED,
        USER_DISCONNECT_REQUEST
    }
    volatile private ConnectionState connectionState = ConnectionState.DISCONNECTED;

    volatile private BluetoothSocket btSocket;
    volatile private BluetoothDevice btDevice;
    volatile private InputStream inStream;
    volatile private OutputStream outStream;

    private RazorListener razorListener;
    private boolean callbacksEnabled = true;

    BluetoothThread btThread;

    private int numConnectAttempts;

    // Object pools
    private ObjectPool<float[]> float3Pool = new ObjectPool<float[]>(new ObjectPool.ObjectFactory<float[]>() {
        @Override
        public float[] newObject() {
            return new float[3];
        }
    });
    private ObjectPool<float[]> float9Pool = new ObjectPool<float[]>(new ObjectPool.ObjectFactory<float[]>() {
        @Override
        public float[] newObject() {
            return new float[9];
        }
    });

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * Must be called from the thread where you want receive the RazorListener callbacks! So if you
     * want to manipulate Android UI from the callbacks you have to call this from your main/UI
     * thread.
     *
     * @param btDevice {@link android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice BluetoothDevice} holding the Razor
     *      AHRS to connect to.
     * @param razorListener {@link RazorListener} that will be notified of Razor AHRS events.
     * @throws RuntimeException thrown if one of the parameters is null.
     */
    public RazorAHRS(BluetoothDevice btDevice, RazorListener razorListener)
            throws RuntimeException {
        this(btDevice, razorListener, RazorOutputMode.CALIBRATED_SENSOR_DATA);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * Must be called from the thread where you want receive the RazorListener callbacks! So if you
     * want to manipulate Android UI from the callbacks you have to call this from your main/UI
     * thread.
     *
     * @param btDevice {@link android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice BluetoothDevice} holding the Razor
     *      AHRS to connect to.
     * @param razorListener {@link RazorListener} that will be notified of Razor AHRS events.
     * @param razorOutputMode {@link RazorOutputMode} that you desire.
     * @throws RuntimeException thrown if one of the parameters is null.
     */
    public RazorAHRS(BluetoothDevice btDevice, RazorListener razorListener, RazorOutputMode razorOutputMode)
            throws RuntimeException {
        if (btDevice == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("BluetoothDevice can not be null.");
        this.btDevice = btDevice;

        if (razorListener == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("RazorListener can not be null.");
        this.razorListener = razorListener;

        if (razorOutputMode == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("RazorMode can not be null.");
        this.razorOutputMode = razorOutputMode;
    }

    /**
     * @return <code>true</code> if listener callbacks are currently enabled, <code>false</code> else.
     */
    public boolean getCallbacksEnabled() {
        return callbacksEnabled;
    }

    /**
     * Enables/disables listener callbacks.
     * @param enabled
     */
    public void setCallbacksEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        callbacksEnabled = enabled;
    }

    /**
     * Connect and start reading. Both is done asynchronously. {@link RazorListener#onConnectOk()}
     * or {@link RazorListener#onConnectFail(IOException)} callbacks will be invoked.
     * 
     * @param numConnectAttempts Number of attempts to make when trying to connect. Often connecting
     *      only works on the 2rd try or later. Bluetooth hooray.
     */
    public void asyncConnect(int numConnectAttempts) {
        if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "asyncConnect() BEGIN");
        // Disconnect and wait for running thread to end, if needed
        if (btThread != null) {
            asyncDisconnect();
            try {
                btThread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        }

        // Bluetooth thread not running any more, we're definitely in DISCONNECTED state now

        // Create new thread to connect to Razor AHRS and read input
        this.numConnectAttempts = numConnectAttempts;
        connectionState = ConnectionState.CONNECTING;
        btThread = new BluetoothThread();
        btThread.start();
        if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "asyncConnect() END");
    }

    /**
     * Disconnects from Razor AHRS. If still connecting this will also cancel the connection process.
     */
    public void asyncDisconnect() {
        if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "asyncDisconnect() BEGIN");
        synchronized (connectionState) {
            if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "asyncDisconnect() SNYNCHRONIZED");
            // Don't go to USER_DISCONNECT_REQUEST state if we are disconnected already
            if (connectionState == ConnectionState.DISCONNECTED)
                return;

            // This is a wanted disconnect, so we force (blocking) I/O to break
            connectionState = ConnectionState.USER_DISCONNECT_REQUEST;
            closeSocketAndStreams();
        }
        if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "asyncDisconnect() END");
    }

    /**
     * Writes out a string using ASCII encoding. Assumes we're connected. Does not handle
     * exceptions itself.
     * 
     * @param text Text to send out
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void write(String text) throws IOException {
        outStream.write(EncodingUtils.getAsciiBytes(text));
    }

    /**
     * Closes I/O streams and Bluetooth socket.
     */
    private void closeSocketAndStreams() {
        if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "closeSocketAndStreams() BEGIN");
        // Try to switch off streaming output of Razor in preparation of next connect
        try {
            if (outStream != null)
                write("#o0");
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        // Close Bluetooth socket => I/O operations immediately will throw exception
        try {
            if (btSocket != null)
                btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "closeSocketAndStreams() BT SOCKET CLOSED");

        // Close streams
        try {
            if (inStream != null)
                inStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        try {
            if (outStream != null)
                outStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "closeSocketAndStreams() STREAMS CLOSED");

        // Do not set socket and streams null, because input thread might still access them
        //inStream = null;
        //outStream = null;
        //btSocket = null;

        if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "closeSocketAndStreams() END");
    }

    /**
     * Thread that handles connecting to and reading from Razor AHRS. 
     */
    private class BluetoothThread extends Thread {
        byte[] inBuf = new byte[512];
        int inBufPos = 0;

        /**
         * Blocks until it can read one byte of input, assumes we have a connection up and running.
         * 
         * @return One byte from input stream
         * @throws IOException If reading input stream fails
         */
        private byte readByte() throws IOException {
            int in = inStream.read();
            if (in == -1)
                throw new IOException("End of Stream");
            return (byte) in;
        }

        /**
         * Converts a buffer of bytes to an array of floats. This method does not do any error
         * checking on parameter array sizes.
         * @param byteBuf Byte buffer with length of at least <code>numFloats  * 4</code>.
         * @param floatArr Float array with length of at least <code>numFloats</code>.
         * @param numFloats Number of floats to convert
         */
        private void byteBufferToFloatArray(byte[] byteBuf, float[] floatArr, int numFloats) {
            //int numFloats = byteBuf.length / 4;
            for (int i = 0; i < numFloats * 4; i += 4) {
                // Convert from little endian (Razor) to big endian (Java) and interpret as float
                floatArr[i/4] = Float.intBitsToFloat((byteBuf[i] & 0xff) + ((byteBuf[i+1] & 0xff) << 8) +
                        ((byteBuf[i+2] & 0xff) << 16) + ((byteBuf[i+3] & 0xff) << 24));
            }
        }

        /**
         * Parse input stream for given token.
         * @param token Token to find
         * @param in Next byte from input stream
         * @return <code>true</code> if token was found
         */
        private boolean readToken(byte[] token, byte in) {
            if (in == token[inBufPos++]) {
                if (inBufPos == token.length) {
                    // Synch token found
                    inBufPos = 0;
                    if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Token found");
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                inBufPos = 0;
            }

            return false;
        }

        /**
         * Synches with Razor AHRS and sets parameters.
         * @throws IOException
         */
        private void initRazor() throws IOException {
            long t0, t1, t2;

            // Start time
            t0 = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

            /* See if Razor is there */
            // Request synch token to see when Razor is up and running
            final String contactSynchID = "00";
            final String contactSynchRequest = "#s" + contactSynchID;
            final byte[] contactSynchReply = EncodingUtils.getAsciiBytes(SYNCH_TOKEN + contactSynchID + NEW_LINE);
            write(contactSynchRequest);
            t1 = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

            while (true) {
                // Check timeout
                t2 = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                if (t2 - t1 > 200) {
                    // 200ms elapsed since last request and no answer -> request synch again.
                    // (This happens when DTR is connected and Razor resets on connect)
                    write(contactSynchRequest);
                    t1 = t2;
                }
                if (t2 - t0 > INIT_TIMEOUT_MS)
                    // Timeout -> tracker not present
                    throw new IOException("Can not init Razor: response timeout");

                // See if we can read something
                if (inStream.available() > 0) {
                    // Synch token found?
                    if (readToken(contactSynchReply, readByte()))
                        break;
                } else {
                    // No data available, wait
                    delay(5); // 5ms
                }
            }

            /* Configure tracker */
            // Set binary output mode, enable continuous streaming, disable errors and request synch
            // token. So we're good, no matter what state the tracker currently is in.
            final String configSynchID = "01";
            final byte[] configSynchReply = EncodingUtils.getAsciiBytes(SYNCH_TOKEN + configSynchID + NEW_LINE);
            write("#ob#o1#oe0#s" + configSynchID);
            while (!readToken(configSynchReply, readByte())) { } 
        }

        /**
         * Opens Bluetooth connection to Razor AHRS.
         * @throws IOException
         */
        private void connect() throws IOException {     
            // Create Bluetooth socket
            btSocket = btDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID_SPP);
            if (btSocket == null) {
                if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "btSocket is null in connect()");
                throw new IOException("Could not create Bluetooth socket");
            }

            // This could be used to create the RFCOMM socekt on older Android devices where
            //createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord is not present yet.
            /*try {
            Method m = btDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] { int.class });
            btSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(btDevice, Integer.valueOf(1));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IOException("Could not create Bluetooth socket using reflection");
            }*/

            // Connect socket to Razor AHRS
            if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Canceling bt discovery");
            BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery(); // Recommended
            if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Trying to connect() btSocket");
            btSocket.connect();

            // Get the input and output streams
            if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create streams");
            inStream = btSocket.getInputStream();
            outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
            if (inStream == null || outStream == null) {
                if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Could not create I/O stream(s) in connect()");
                throw new IOException("Could not create I/O stream(s)");
            }
        }

        /**
         * Bluetooth I/O thread entry method.
         */
        public void run() {
            if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth I/O thread started");
            try {
                // Check if btDevice is set
                if (btDevice == null) {
                    if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "btDevice is null in run()");
                    throw new IOException("Bluetooth device is null");
                }

                // Make several attempts to connect
                int i = 1;
                while (true) {
                    if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Connect attempt " + i + " of " + numConnectAttempts);
                    sendToParentThread(MSG_ID__CONNECT_ATTEMPT, i);
                    try {
                        connect();
                        break;  // Alrighty!
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Attempt failed: " + e.getMessage());
                        // Maximum number of attempts reached or cancel requested?
                        if (i == numConnectAttempts || connectionState == ConnectionState.USER_DISCONNECT_REQUEST)
                            throw e;

                        // We couldn't connect on first try, manually starting Bluetooth discovery
                        // often helps
                        if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Starting BT discovery");
                        BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().startDiscovery();
                        delay(5000); // 5 seconds - long enough?

                        i++;
                    }
                }

                // Set Razor output mode
                if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Trying to set Razor output mode");
                initRazor();

                // We're connected and initialized (unless disconnect was requested)
                synchronized (connectionState) {
                    if (connectionState == ConnectionState.USER_DISCONNECT_REQUEST) {
                        closeSocketAndStreams();
                        throw new IOException(); // Dummy exception to force disconnect
                    }
                    else connectionState = ConnectionState.CONNECTED;
                }

                // Tell listener we're ready
                sendToParentThread(MSG_ID__CONNECT_OK, null);

                // Keep reading inStream until an exception occurs
                if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Starting input loop");
                while (true) {
                    // Read byte from input stream
                    inBuf[inBufPos++] = (byte) readByte();

                    if (razorOutputMode == RazorOutputMode.YAW_PITCH_ROLL_ANGLES) {
                        if (inBufPos == 12) {   // We received a full frame
                            float[] ypr = float3Pool.get();
                            byteBufferToFloatArray(inBuf, ypr, 3);

                            // Forward to parent thread handler
                            sendToParentThread(MSG_ID__YPR_DATA, ypr);

                            // Rewind input buffer position
                            inBufPos = 0;
                        }
                    } else {    // Raw or calibrated sensor data mode
                        if (inBufPos == 36) {   // We received a full frame
                            float[] amg = float9Pool.get();
                            byteBufferToFloatArray(inBuf, amg, 9);

                            // Forward to parent thread handler
                            sendToParentThread(MSG_ID__AMG_DATA, amg);

                            // Rewind input buffer position
                            inBufPos = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "IOException in Bluetooth thread: " + e.getMessage());
                synchronized (connectionState) {
                    // Don't forward exception if it was thrown because we broke I/O on purpose in
                    // other thread when user requested disconnect
                    if (connectionState != ConnectionState.USER_DISCONNECT_REQUEST) {
                        // There was a true I/O error, cleanup and forward exception
                        closeSocketAndStreams();
                        if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Forwarding exception");
                        if (connectionState == ConnectionState.CONNECTING)
                            sendToParentThread(MSG_ID__CONNECT_FAIL, e);
                        else
                            sendToParentThread(MSG_ID__IO_EXCEPTION_AND_DISCONNECT, e);
                    } else {
                        // I/O error was caused on purpose, socket and streams are closed already
                    }

                    // I/O closed, thread done => we're disconnected now
                    connectionState = ConnectionState.DISCONNECTED;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Sends a message to Handler assigned to parent thread.
         * 
         * @param msgId
         * @param data
         */
        private void sendToParentThread(int msgId, Object o) {
            if (callbacksEnabled)
                parentThreadHandler.obtainMessage(msgId, o).sendToTarget();
        }

        /**
         * Sends a message to Handler assigned to parent thread.
         * 
         * @param msgId
         * @param data
         */
        private void sendToParentThread(int msgId, int i) {
            if (callbacksEnabled)
                parentThreadHandler.obtainMessage(msgId, i, -1).sendToTarget();
        }

        /**
         * Wrapper for {@link Thread#sleep(long)};
         * @param ms Milliseconds
         */
        void delay(long ms) {
            try {
                sleep(ms); // Sleep 5ms
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handler that forwards messages to the RazorListener callbacks. This handler runs in the
     * thread this RazorAHRS object was created in and receives data from the Bluetooth I/O thread.
     */
    private Handler parentThreadHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                case MSG_ID__YPR_DATA:  // Yaw, pitch and roll data
                    float[] ypr = (float[]) msg.obj;
                    razorListener.onAnglesUpdate(ypr[0], ypr[1], ypr[2]);
                    float3Pool.put(ypr);
                    break;
                case MSG_ID__AMG_DATA:  // Accelerometer, magnetometer and gyroscope data
                    float[] amg = (float[]) msg.obj;
                    razorListener.onSensorsUpdate(amg[0], amg[1], amg[2], amg[3], amg[4], amg[5],
                            amg[6], amg[7], amg[8]);
                    float9Pool.put(amg);
                    break;
                case MSG_ID__IO_EXCEPTION_AND_DISCONNECT:
                    razorListener.onIOExceptionAndDisconnect((IOException) msg.obj);
                    break;
                case MSG_ID__CONNECT_ATTEMPT:
                    razorListener.onConnectAttempt(msg.arg1, numConnectAttempts);
                    break;
                case MSG_ID__CONNECT_OK:
                    razorListener.onConnectOk();
                    break;
                case MSG_ID__CONNECT_FAIL:
                    razorListener.onConnectFail((IOException) msg.obj);
                break;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Any chance you were able to figure out the cause of this?